# Mysql Allocates too much ram

Tags: mysql

I am using a 4GB VPS from 1&1 and the main mysqld process is allocating up to 2GB, though never using more than 100mb from them. Should I be worried about this and how can I optimize it? (Running CentOS and no tunes done on mysql server)

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
```

Comment: Please add your my.cnf configuration

Comment: Where do you see that "the main mysqld process is allocating up to 2GB, though never using more than 100mb from them"?

Comment: using "top" in linux :)

Comment: You forgot to show the output. We can't read your screen since we're not the NSA :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try running mysqltuner and then change the setup as per the instructions.

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl`

give execute permission for the file and then run it.

`perl mysqltuner.pl`

Comment: Please keep in mind that downloading and executing random scripts off the internet should be considered unsafe.

Comment: it is a read-only script, how should I use it ?